# Kali installation on vm´s

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, virtual-machine

the question is directed more towards the installation options in virtual machines, I would like to know if I can install kali but inside the virtual machine, that is, download it already within the virtual machine created with a Linux operating system, do everything from there... I would also like to know if when downloading kali either through the option of wsl, uSB, hyper v even directly on my computer my security could be more vulnerable....?????

Comment: The thing is: If you're asking this question then Kali definitely ISN'T for you something the answer below subtly suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Kali is usually run as a Virtual Machine or from a pendrive for security and convenience. [Ready-made VMs](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines) are available for VMWare and VirtuaBox on Windows environment, and KVM/QEMU on Linux. Kali has extensive [documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/) which explains all the installation options, and otherwise how to run it without problems. Worth reading, as Kali's very different from your average desktop distro.